# Why I can't get the value of an added radiobuttons or edittexts?

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, radio-group

I've done an app how add dynamically to a linearlayout some layout customized. My problem is when I want to retrieve the value of some component of this layout added.

I have three types of XML that I can add dynamically.

**ONE**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tv_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_container"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$$$"
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rg_answers"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ll_main_padding_top">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**TWO**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tv_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_container"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$$$"
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/rg_answers"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ll_main_padding_top">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_yes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb_value_no"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableBottom="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>


    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

**THREE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tv_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_container"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="$$$"
        android:id="@+id/tv_question"
        android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_answer"
        android:textColor="@color/ferro_palette_black"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've done the next method to inflate and get values.

```
public void addQuestion(LinearLayout mRootLayout, Context _c, int quiz_type, String question, int order, int answer_id)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _c.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        int id_layout = -1;
        if(quiz_type == 1) {
            id_layout = R.layout.quiz_type_one;
        }else if(quiz_type == 2){
            id_layout = R.layout.quiz_type_two;
        }else if(quiz_type == 3){
            id_layout = R.layout.quiz_type_three;
        }

        View mChildView = inflater.inflate(id_layout, mRootLayout, false);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        mRootLayout.addView(mChildView, params);

        TextView tv_question = (TextView) mChildView.findViewById(R.id.tv_question);
        tv_question.setText(question);

        if(quiz_type == 1) {
            RadioGroup rg_answers = (RadioGroup)mChildView.findViewById(R.id.rg_answers);
            int value = rg_answers.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        }else if(quiz_type == 2){
            RadioGroup rg_answers = (RadioGroup)mChildView.findViewById(R.id.rg_answers);
            int value = rg_answers.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        }else if(quiz_type == 3){
            EditText et_answer = (EditText)mChildView.findViewById(R.id.et_answer);
            String value = et_answer.getText().toString();
        }

    }
```

For some reason, everytime I'm getting -1 or "" in the variable value. Why??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are You sure that quiz type is correctly transferred to addQuestion()?

Comment: You can easily find the problem by debugging your code.

Comment: Yes, it's OK the type.

Comment: "aegan" your answer is the best. Very useful.

Answer (score 1):

by seeing your code, in this method `addQuestion()`, you are inflating you layouts fresh,

so in below part of method where you are trying to catch the values, it will always be -1 and "" as you are trying to read values out of freshly inflated views.

if you want to get values which user has entered, try implementing OnClick listeners, or pehaps a button pressing which you initiate value read.